# targeting form fields at once(JavaScript shorthand kinda?)

Tags: javascript

So long story short, i have some forms (2) of them that, need different types of validation...for the sake of argument, lets say i want to check for empties or "" values on all of the forms fields.

if i have for example 3 fields, how can i check for empties in those 3 fields at the same
time without writing code for all of them...

what i mean is...for example:

heres some sample code:

JS:

```
var test = document.getElementById("loginUsername");//this is the username field//

test.onfocus = removeVal;
test.onblur = inserDefVal;

function removeVal(){
    if(test.value == "Enter your Username"){
        test.value = "";    
    }
}


function inserDefVal(){
    if(test.value == ""){
        test.value = "Enter your Username"; 
    }   
}
```

now although i have those 2 functions to check for field values, if i have 3 fields, that means id have to have a list of

```
test.onfocus = removeVal;
test.onblur = inserDefVal;

test2.onfocus = removeVal;
test2.onblur = inserDefVal;

test2.onfocus = removeVal;
test2.onblur = inserDefVal;
```

now imagine all other fields in a form that i want to check for empties...ill have a SUPER long list lol..

so my quesiton is, is there a way to maybe, put all these into one...
and or maybe

like a general function/or action that says something like

(logic i mean)
here comes pseudo code --

`if(this.value =="") do xyz`....and "this" being the field im mousing over.

or if say, i was to somehow..for example, put all the button names/variable names in an Array,  and say its called ArraOfButtons, and then

```
ArrayOfButtons.onmouseover/out = function.....
```

I hope im not too confusing...im just looking for a way to write better,faster cleaner code because as you can see above, if i have those test1/2/3 to just check for empties, then imagine checking for dates and other values....the page would be SUPER long.

in short, im looking for like a CSS shorthand kinda thing where, instead of one writing

```
margin-top:10px / margin-bottom:10px / margin-left/right:10px
```

one would just do

margin:10px;

Any tips/links/info i gladly appreciate.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input class="hint" type="text" name="username" value="Enter your Username" data-hint="Enter your Username" />
<input class="hint" type="text" name="email" value="Enter your Email" data-hint="Enter your Email" />
<input class="hint" type="text" name="city" value="Enter your City" data-hint="Enter your City" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    // handler for form elements when they receive onfocus
    function removeVal() {
        // get default value from attribute 'data-hint' and compare the current value
        if ( this.value == this.getAttribute( 'data-hint' ) ) {
            // if current value equal default value, set value to empty
            this.value = "";
        }
    }

    // handler for form elements when they receive onblur
    function inserDefVal() {
        // if current value equal empty
        if ( this.value == "" ) {
            // get default value from attribute and set her to field value.
            // if attribute not found to set empty
            this.value = this.getAttribute( 'data-hint' ) || "";
        }   
    }

    // search elements by className
    function addEvents( className ) {

        var i, j, elem, all, elems = [];

        // If your browser supports "getElementsByClassName", use it
        if ( document.getElementsByClassName ) {
            // search elements by class name
            elems = document.getElementsByClassName( className );
        } else {
            // search elements by class name for IE7-8.
            // IE7-8 not support native "getElementsByClassName"
            all = document.getElementsByTagName( "*" );
            // pass on all the elements
            for( j = 0; elem = all[ j++ ]; ) {
                // check for the presence of our class name
                if ( (" " + elem.className + " ").indexOf( " " + className + " " ) >= 0 ) {
                    // is found the className, put an item in the stack
                    elems[ elems.length ] = elem;
                }
            }
        }

        // hang on found items the events
        for( i = 0; elem = elems[ i++ ]; ) {
            elem.onfocus = removeVal;
            elem.onblur = inserDefVal;
        }
    }

    // initialize elements by className "hint"
    addEvents( 'hint' );

</script>
```

Comment: Your Javascript lvl is WAY above mine....lol i dont understand how it works but it works lol. i thought a simple loop like the one below from dfreeman would work, i had tried something similar, even in jQuery and it would never work....ill keep looking at this lol. thanks

Comment: Like I said below, I'm a fan of this answer, but if you're still looking for something a little easier to grok, I threw this at Chrome and it seems to work fine: https://gist.github.com/2324797

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery, you can give all of the fields a class and access them as such

```
$('.inputClass')
```

Or via element

```
$('input')
```

This will allow you to perform an action against all matching elements.

Comment: LMFAO...i MUST be tired...i had it the whole time...i had it exactly the way you had it and so since it didnt work, KNOWING it should, after a while i gave up and decided to ask in regular .js  After all this, when i look at the script tag...it wasnt working because i guess SOMEHOW i erased the link to jquery lol...ahahahaha man. im going to bed lol. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over every single form field in your page, you could do something like

```
var formFields = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i=0; i < formFields.length; i++) {
    var field = formFields[i];
    field.onfocus = removeVal;
    field.onblur = inserDefVal;
}
```

You could also filter in that loop based on the specific type of the input or any arbitrary class you might have assigned to your inputs.

Comment: Hey Dfreeman. yeah i tried something similar b4 i posted...and to begin with, i tested a nearly identical loop and after "var field = formFields[i];" i put in a "document.write(field.value + "<br/>");" to see if all the values printed, which they did/do. And then i commented out that line and put in what you put in which is "field.onfocus" etc...and to no avail. nothing happens.

Comment: Ah well, @devote's answer is more complete anyway, so even if this worked out of the box (instinctively I feel like it should, but I'm probably overlooking something), I'd go with that instead.